# What is the best way to deal with coil whine on a Mac laptop?

Tags: hardware, power-management

I have owned my MacBook Pro for a little over a year, and it has been serving me really well. Ever since I first opened it, the device was experiencing the Retina "staining" issue, so Apple recently replaced the display. Due to an issue with the replacement part, Apple also did a second display replacement.

Though I'm not sure it's related to Apple servicing the device, I have recently noticed something that seems a lot like coil whine on my Mac. If I put my ear up to the keyboard, something that is like an electronic buzzing can be heard. Lately, I can hear this noise at a normal sitting distance. Interestingly, though running disk intensive applications like BlackMagic Disk Speed Test intensify this noise, it seems to be coming from all parts of the logic board.

Assuming this is coil while, what would be the best way to deal with this issue? I have talked to Apple support online, who advised the usual troubleshooting steps of an SMC reset, among a few others. I restarted in Safe Mode, reset both the SMC and NVRAM, as well as ran Apple Diagnostics, all of which neither resolved the issue nor indicated any hardware issue.

First of all, could this seemingly new issue be related to Apple servicing the device twice? Also, since this device is covered by an AppleCare Protection Plan (and possibly an additional warranty from the recent repair), do you think Apple would replace the device or logic board if I can prove that this does occur? The problem with showing this to someone is that it is faint enough that you would not able to hear this in an Apple store.

I would appreciate any advice on how to present this issue to a technician or otherwise resolve the problem without a visit to the Apple store. Thanks!

MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015), 
macOS 10.13.3

Comment: See the Apple store....

Comment: Thanks @SolarMike. I think I will have to make an Apple store appointment, but do you know how I can show this to them in a noisy environment or what they may do about this?

Comment: Ask for a quieter area...

Comment: @Jake3231 Did you ever resolve this issue? I had my MBP 15" serviced at an Authorized Service Provider (changed battery and topcase), and when I got it back it has started making coil whine sounds when carrying out moderate/heavy tasks on the SSD.